# Packaging large database with android

Tags: android

I'm looking to packing a large sqlite database with an android app, about 200-300MB. From what I've read, my options are putting it in the assets folder, and coping it out at runtime, resulting in duplicate data, or downloading the database from the web at runtime. I don't want to create a webserver for this app, so I was thinking of creating a seperate app that just installs the database to get around the data duplication problem.

All of those are pretty crummy, and I was wondering if there is a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test of [apk expansion files](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html). I created a test app with a 100 MB sqlite database, uploaded the apk and database to the play store. I then downloaded the app onto the phone, the database was downloaded at the same time. The database was automatically renamed and placed in the publicly accessible directory:

```
/storage/sdcard0/Android/obb/com.example.app/main.1.com.example.app.obb
```

The app was able to open the database without any problems, but required external read and write permissions. The new and original database are bit for bit, the same. This appears to be the best solution for my use case.

A few issues, the new android developer console does not support uploading expansion files, so the old one needs to be used. Google only allows 2 expansion files, so that may be an issue for some use cases. Google say that you must not rename or delete the file, and that your app must be able to download the file from Google itself if it wasn't automatically installed.

Answer (score 3):

First, I don't think you are allowed to put a 200-300MB database in your assets folder and distribute it as a single apk, since the hard limit for an apk file size is (as per google's documentation) 50 MB and I doubt that your db will compress that far.. Google introduced the "APK expansion files" for packaging large files with your apk. You can read all about those here: http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

I think (but I have no experience with expansion files myself) that this will not fix the issue you mentioned about having to deal with duplicate data because of the requirement to copy out your database file, but at least this will help you in the sense that you won't have to host your database file on your own webserver. I quickly scanned the documentation on the link I gave above and it clearly states that you should NOT throw away the expansion files when you are done with them, so no help on that part.

Of course, for the "setting up your own webserver part": I wouldn't even bother setting up my own webserver. There are plenty of parties out there that provide you some file hosting service. Probably you will have to pay for the bandwidth, but hey.. if people download your db file a lot, that also means that your app is doing well ;-)

Comment: It looks like it renames the expansion files to obb (opaque binary blobs). Is it possible to use the obb file as a sqlite database inplace without coping it? That would be a preferable solution.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing when I wrote my answer, but I have no experience with the use of expansion files. My guess would be that, just like an .apk file, the expansion files are zipped. I don't think that you can then use the database file in that .obb in-place. But to be honest, I really don't know. If this could be done, then for sure it would be the preferable solution..

Comment: In the overview, it recommends using a compressed file to conserve bandwidth, and the fact that they are opaque binary blobs, indicate to me that they aren't compressed automatically.

Comment: Well if that is truly the case, then I think you would have a valid reason for NOT using compression in this case. However.. You will have to try this out to be 100% sure I'm afraid (or find someone that already tried this). Good luck! (I'm starring this question in the hope that you will report your findings ;-))